# C - Get PID of process opened with popen

Tags: c, popen, kill, pid, ptrace

I have a program written in C, which opens another program using popen. I 'd like to get the pid of that program or some kind of handler for it, so as to kill it after a certain time limit, or if it exceeds some ram, and stdout limits. I think this must be done with ptrace, which needs the PID, which I don't know how to obtain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just write your own implementation of `popen` that returns the PID. It's much less ugly than some crazy hackery around the existing `popen`. You can find source code to `popen` implementations all over the net. [Here's one](http://www.koders.com/c/fid3204C91ABD374457CC6CDF5DCAB322544D646DB0.aspx?s=netbsd#L10).

Comment: Thank you very much. Seems to be the best solution.

Comment: Link to popen source is broken

Comment: Here is one that works today: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/3884bfe9661955543ce203c60f9225bbdf33f6bb/libc/unistd/popen.c

Answer (score 0):

You might also be able to use ulimits and other tricks to achieve the desired functionality without using ptrace. You can do this by writing your command to be something akin to `"sh -c 'ulimit [ulimit strings]; whatever-command'"`. `ulimit -v` takes care of RAM limit. CPU time limit (`ulimit -t`) might be able to approximate time limit; if not, and if you're willing to rewrite `popen`, then you can stick a call to `setitimer` in there. stdout is less straightforward; but if you are logging stdout with a shell redirect then I think `ulimit -f` will do it. If you're reading child's stdout in the parent you can track it yourself, and kill with a signal if they go too long.