# from where pclose gets pid

Tags: c++, c

in the documention of **pclose** function there is a part of code which  illustrates how the pclose() function might be implemented

```
int pclose(FILE *stream)

{
    int stat;
    pid_t pid;


    pid = <pid for process created for stream by popen()>
    (void) fclose(stream);
    while (waitpid(pid, &stat, 0) == -1) {
        if (errno != EINTR){
            stat = -1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return(stat);
}
```

so i'm interesting , form where he gets "pid for process created for stream by popen()". is there some place where this value is stored?

Comment: That is very OS specific, I think.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462442/c-get-pid-of-process-opened-with-popen

Comment: thank's @kugg , it's the one of solution of my problem, which I already implemented, but it would be good to use standard function and get that pid but as I understand from comments and answers, it is not possible.

Comment: If it helps you may want to look at this [implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548063/kill-a-process-started-with-popen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From some internal state owned by the library that implements `popen()` and `pclose()`. Most probably it will be stored as a field in the (internal) `FILE` structure.

Comment: so as i understand , there is no portable way to get this field ?

Comment: For that, see kugg's comment (i.e. [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462442/c-get-pid-of-process-opened-with-popen)).